# Automatically sending an activation key by SMS or email after registration

Tags: ios, email, sms

I'm working on a free iOS app; at the end of the registration (when the user has registered a good phone number and good email address) I want the user to enter a code which he has received on his phone or email.

But the problem is how to send automatically a SMS or an e-mail programmatically that contains the code?

I don't want the user to be redirected to a specific view controller to compose a message by himself (like with `MFMessageComposeViewController` or `MFEmailComposeViewController`)
just and only just the same appearance of SMS or email sent to users but with a different activation key (for the keys, I think about auto generated keys stored in a database).

And I think about the same way for forgotten identifiers, the user enter his email address or his phone number in a text field, and a message is automatically sent with the password and the username of the user, if the email address or the phone number entered is already existing in the database, if it is not, it shows an alert view with an error.

Does anyone have an idea for how to do this?

Comment: No way you will get this accepted to the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following services Parse.com + mailgun.  Search on Parse.com for a tutorial using mailgun and it should accomplish what you are trying to do.  On a side not, be careful when creating an app which does not allow the user to use it until they enter some access code, it is against the Apple rules and could lead to rejection.

Comment: Thank you for the tip ! But the utility of the access code is to prepare multi accounts, I don't hide the fact that my app is oriented social relations with feedback, but, do you think that to begin the first version of my app, use activation keys is useless or useful ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a server that generates this activation code that is sent to the user.

When the user enters the text field with the code he got it should be sent back to the server with an http request (use [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html) ). The server should response to the http request with approval or error whether the code is right, or send the username and password and any other data the user needs to continue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will think about the solution, hosting with OVH or another provider (but I think OVH offers well solutions) :)